# Akka Scheduler: How akka scheduler work?

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, scheduled-tasks

I am going to explore `Akka Scheduler`. As of my assumptions, the scheduler run the scheduled task within specific duration of time in another thread.  According to the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/scheduler.html#Some_examples), they are used `Runnable` object with in scheduler. This is not clear, why they are used `Runnable` object and without call `start()` on runnable, the new thread stack not produce. Or `Scheduler` doesn't create a septate thread for running scheduled task?

How `akka` scheduler work under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

When i used `Akka Scheduler`, i tried to research source code for obtaining more knowledge - https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Scheduler.scala

As you can see, `Akka Scheduler` uses `ExecutorContect` (wrapper under `ForkJoinPool`) as implicit parameter to onvoke new `Runnable`and sends message to another actors via  `receiver ! message` by leveraging `fire and forget` pattern.

Another important classes for understanding the full picture are `FiniteDuration` (it allows to set up delay time), `Cancellable` (it allows to cancel the execution of the scheduled operation), they are using in the most methods related with scheduling processes (e.g. scheduleOnce, i used this for time synchronization between actors)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `start()` on `Runnable`. You are mixing `Thread` and `Runnable`. 
Under the hood, the `Scheduler` use a `Dispatcher`, which can be viewed,to simplify, as an akka layer on top of some `ThreadPool`. To execute you task, akka will submit your task (the `Runnable`) to this pool, then the pool will have one his `Thread` to call the `run()` method of the task.

Answer (score -1):

Go through this :
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html

Also try this :
http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/04/23/a-handful-akka-techniques/

Comment: Please read my question carefully, i want to know, how scheduler work under the hood and how thread are manage in schduler

Comment: It is based on job bucket scheduler . that two links provide you more inner links with example. that's why I include that links.